# Limit of integral as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \colon [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$f(x) = \frac{57^{x^2+1} + 3}{e^{x^2} + 1113337x^2 + 1113339x^{\frac{3}{2}} + 1113341x + 1}$$
Then,what is the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1f(x)^ndx\right)^{\frac1{n}}$$

I am dumbstuck on this problem. Do we have to calculate the supremum of the given function, since the $p$ norm approaches the sup-norm as $p$ tends to infinity? Any elementary method? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Yes, the limit is $\|f\|_{\infty} = f(0)$.

Comment: @ Hans Engler as far as I can see $f$ is not a decreasing function. How did you come up with $f(0)$ instead of $\sup \{f(x):0 \leq x \leq 1\}$?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3263668).