# How to find the following limit regarding integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(x)=\frac{57^{x^2+1}+3}{e^{x^2}+1113337x^2+1113339x^\frac{3}{2}+1113341x+1}.$$ Find the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^ndx\right)^\frac{1}{n}.$$

I am trying to evaluate this limit. I know that the limit will be the maximun value of $f(x)$ on the interval. But how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to go is by looking at [the graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20of%20(57%5E(x%5E2%2B1)%2B3)%2F(e%5E(x%5E2)%2B1113337x%5E2%2B1113339x%5E(3%2F2)%2B1113341x%2B1)), which shows us clearly that $f$ is a convex function, so must achieve its maximum value at one of the endpoints of the interval. From there, we need only calculate the two values, and conclude which is greater.

As an alternative, we can show analytically that the function is convex in the given interval, though it isn't pretty. One thing that will make it a little easier is using the quotient rule. If $u$ and $v$ are differentiable functions with $v$ everywhere positive and $w=\frac{u}{v},$ then $$w'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}=\frac{u'}{v}-\frac{uv'}{v^2},$$ or equivalently, $$w'=\frac{u'-wv'}{v}.$$  Given any differentiable functions $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ and $\hat w=\frac{\hat u}{\hat v},$ we likewise have $$\hat w=\frac{\hat u'-\hat w\hat v'}{\hat v}.$$ In particular, when $\hat w=w',$ we have $\hat u=u'-wv'$ and $\hat v=v,$ so $$w''=\frac{(u'-wv')'-w'v'}{v}=\frac{u''-(wv')'-w'v'}{v}=\frac{u''-wv''-2w'v'}{v}.$$ Thus, recalling that $w'=\frac{u'-wv'}{v},$ we obtain $$w''=\frac{u''-wv''}{v}-2\frac{u'-wv'}{v}\cdot\frac{v'}{v}=\frac{u''-wv''}{v}+2\frac{w\bigl(v'\bigr)^2-u'v'}{v^2}.$$ Recalling that $w=\frac{u}{v},$ we then have $$w''=\frac{u''}{v}-\frac{2u'v'+uv''}{v^2}+\frac{2u\bigl(v'\bigr)^2}{v^3}.$$ Thus, since $v$ is everywhere positive, then $w''>0$ if and only if $$w''v^3>0,$$ or equivalently, $$u''v^2-2u'vv'-uvv''+2u\bigl(v'\bigr)^2>0.\tag{$\star$}$$

In particular, letting $u=57^{x^2+1}+3$ and $v=e^{x^2}+1113337x^2+1113339x^\frac{3}{2}+1113341x+1,$ we can easily see that $u$ and $v$ are differentiable in $(0,1)$ and that $v$ is positive there, so showing that $f(x)$ is convex is equivalent to proving $(\star)$ for these particular $u$ and $v.$

Unfortunately, that's as far as I have time to get you right now. I may come back to expand on it later.

Comment: This was a theoretical question. Using the graph we can do. Can we answer without using it

Comment: You could instead calculate the first derivative, and show that the only local extremum of $f(x)$ in the interval $(0,1)$ is a local minimum, whence it achieves its maximum on one of the two endpoints. However, the derivative is extremely messy and hard to work with. Alternatively, you could find the second derivative, and show that it is positive on the interval $(0,1),$ which leads us to the same conclusion. However, once again, this is hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the function almost has values close to 0 in $(0,1]$ the whole function is dominated by terms $111337x^2+111339x^{1.5}+111341x$ thus max value of the function is at $x=0$ which is $30$ and then the values fall drastically to 0 check at $0.1,0.001$ you can use Taylor expansion for terms like $e^{x^2},57^{x^2}$ etc thus $ lim_{n\to \infty}(\int_0^1 f(x)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\approx lim_{n\to \infty}(\int_0^1(30^n)dx)^{\frac{1}{n}}=lim_{n\to \infty}30^{n\frac{1}{n}}=30$

Comment: Edited it. I am trying to give an approach which uses very little calculus

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = 1113341$. $f(x)$ is positive on $[0, 1]$, and $f(0) = 30$. We want to show that this expression is non-negative:
$$(30 - f(x)) \cdot \frac {57^{x^2 + 1} + 3} {f(x)} = \\
\underbrace {30 e^{x^2}}_{\geq 30} - 57^{x^2 + 1} +
 \underbrace{30 (a - 4) x^2 + 30 (a - 2) x^{3/2}}_{\geq 0} + 30 a x + 27 \geq \\
30 a x + 57 - 57^{x^2 + 1}.$$
Let $x = \sqrt u, \, g(u) = 30 a \sqrt u + 57 - 57^{u + 1}, \, u \in [0, 1]$, then
$$g'(u) = \frac {15 a} {\sqrt u} - 57^{u + 1} \ln 57.$$
Both terms are decreasing, therefore
$$g'(u) \geq g'(1) > 0, \\
g(u) \geq g(0) = 0, \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \| f \|_n = \| f \|_\infty = 30.$$